# How to apply flex-grow?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a flex row with a growth of 2 and then a wrap but can't understand why it is not working properly.

Here is the CSS and HTML.

```css
    .flex {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    } 

    .flex1 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: 50px;
    } 

    .flex2 {
    height: 50px; 
    width: 50px; 
    background-color: green; 
    margin-left: 50px;
    } 

    .flexcontainer {
    display: flex; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 2;
    flex-direction: row;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="flexcontainer">
     <div class="flex">
      <div class="flex1">
       <div class="flex2">
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: flex-grow should be applied to child elements (I think you need to read more around flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

The way you implement the flex-grow is totally wrong because the flex-grow have to be applied to child elements as shown in below code snippet as a example.

```css
#content {
  display: flex;

  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.box {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.box1 {
  flex-grow: 2;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<h4>This is a Flex-Grow</h4>
<div id="content">
  <div class="box" style="background-color:red;">A</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color:yellow;">C</div>
  <div class="box1" style="background-color:brown;">D</div>
  <div class="box1" style="background-color:lightgreen;">E</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color:brown;">F</div>
</div>
```

To read more about flex-grow, you should learn from there : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow